# Почему функция WinExec возвращает 0?

Tags: c, winapi

Как вызываю функцию:

```
UINT result = WinExec("my.exe -i -a", SW_HIDE);
```

`my.exe` находится в той же директории, что и исполняемый файл. `-i -a` соответственно флаги. В cmd `my.exe -i -a` нормально отрабатывает. В моём приложении WinExec возвращает 0. В документации по данной функции написано, что если функция возвращает 0, значит `The system is out of memory or resources` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec). В диспетчере задач мониторю производительность ОС и во время выполнения моего приложения показатели нормальные (остаётся много оперативной памяти). Есть предположение, что недостаточно памяти для создания виртуального адресного пространства для запускаeмого (`my.exe`) приложения. Но как-то сомнительный вариант. По сути, оба приложения требуют не много памяти. Если проблема с ресурсами, то каких ресурсов может не хватать для выполнения WinExec?

Comment: Не забивайте мозг устаревшими сущностями, есть же CreateProcess. О чём явно сказано по ссылке: Note  *This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. Applications should use the CreateProcess function.*

Comment: Фразу "The system is out of memory or resources" следует понимать как "Функции HeapAlloc не удалось выделить память". Это может произойти далеко не обязательно из-за нехватки памяти, а, скажем, из-за бага с переполнением буфера в другом коде, который в свою очередь привел к повреждению служебных областей памяти.